# Problema con .htacess

Tags: web, apache

Estoy teniendo un problema con el archivo .htacess de mi servidor.

Tengo dos paginas, una en `public_html` y la otra en `dominio.com`, esta ultima se encuentra en `public_html`.

Si reemplazo el htacess en `public_html`, en `dominio.com` deja de funcionar y viceversa.

Hay alguna forma de hacer que el archivo .htacess, pueda contener la configuracion para ambos sitios?

Este es el contenido de mi .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dominio\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dominio.com/
RewriteRule (.*) /dominio.com/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolvi. 
Sobre esta linea  `RewriteRule (.*) /dominio.com/$1 [L]` agregue la ubicacion index. Quedando de esta forma `RewriteRule (.*) /dominio.com/index.php$ - [L]`